# Unrecognized expresssion error?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
<li class ="block" ng-repeat="i in items | searchFor:searchString" id={{i.title}}>
        <a><img class="gallery" id={{i.title}} ng-src="{{i.image}}" title="{{i.title}}" /></a>
        <a href="{{i.image}}" download><button id="eye" title="Preview"></button></a>
        <p>{{i.title}}</p>

    </li>
```

**Items list**

```
$scope.items = [
 {
url: '#',
title: 'Mountain',
image: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1443890923422-7819ed4101c0'
 }];
```

This throws an error

> jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1443890923422-7819ed4101c0

Comment: which version of jquery are you using? and which version of angularjs

Comment: well, that seems to meet the minimum jquery requirement for angular 1.3 ... I take it, as I asked for versions of two products (jquery AND angularjs), your answer refers to the version of jquery, and I should just "guess" you're using a stable version of angular

Comment: angular js is 1.0.7

Comment: It seems there is an error somewhere. The sample code works successfully with **angularjs 1.0.7** and **jquery 2.1.1**. Example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/aqqd9h38/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error occurs here

```
 <a href="{{i.image}}" download><button id="eye" title="Preview"></button></a>
```

Try to change the href to ng-href

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs since you are using href instead of ng-href since {{i.image}} is not evaluated

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref